# Books about English Writing

Tags: resources, book-rec

Can you recommend a good reference book about the basics of English writing?

Answer (score 9):

Strunk and White: [The Elements of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style)

Answer (score 5):

Try these:

[On Writing Well, 30th Anniversary Edition: The Classic Guide to Writing Nonfiction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060891548)

[100 Ways to Improve Your Writing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451627210)

Answer (score 4):

- [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html)